# what does the following php regular expression evaluates to?

Tags: php, regex

I come across a php regular expression, mentioned below, I am not sure why `\q\` is used in it, can anybody help me to understand this?

```
$strBuildTitle="SOME URL";
$patterns[0] = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\q\ ]/";        
$replacements[0] = " ";

$strBuildTitle = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $strBuildTitle);
```

I believe it tries to remove any non-alpha-numeric character from the given url, not sure why `\q\` is used here. Is is related with removal of quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\q` and `\` aren't valid [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_Sequences_in_C).

In double quoted strings, it's PHP's policy to ignore those and replace them with their apparent value, meaning `\` simply becoming  and `\q` becoming `q`. The latter case already being covered by `[a-z]`.

Comment: Nah. PHP will keep backslashes before unknown C string escapes. Meaning `"\q"` will remain `\q` in the string value until it reaches PCRE. It is PCRE which will equate it to just the letter `q` in that context.

Comment: Just curious. What's `print "\j"` giving you?

Comment: `<? print "\j"; ?>` gives me a an output of `... \j ...`